# USB ports are not responsive after closing laptop overnight (Debian 12)

Tags: debian, usb

This is the second time this has happened in a row so I figured I would make a question about it. But basically, when I am done working on my laptop for the day, I close it (not shut it down), and resume the following morning. This is what I typically do except today and yesterday, all my USB ports were no longer responsive including my external mouse and keyboard. In order to fix the issue, I have had to restart my computer. When I run `lsusb`, I can see that all my devices are still recognized, they just won't work.

By the way, I have recently upgraded to Debian 12 (from 11) so I wonder if the issue is related to that.

If anyone could enlighten me what is going on and how it could be solved, it would be greatly appreciated. Someone on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69594/my-usb-ports-randomly-stop-working-till-a-reboot) had a similar issue but the linked [answer](https://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-usb-stops-working-problem-in-ubuntu.html) is from 2009 and is for Ubuntu, not Debian, so I am a little hesitant to try something similar.

Comment: If your Debian 12 can still boot and work normally with the older Debian 11 kernel you could check if this problem happens when using kernel 5.10 instead of 6.1 (that would be a first step about figuring out what part could cause this).

Comment: Yeah I suppose so. It's a weird thing to test since I have to wait a long time and it is non-deterministic. For example this morning my peripherals worked for a couple hours before they eventually stopped responding. But I'll try

Comment: @A.B okay it has been a few days now on the old kernel so I am pretty confident that v6.1 of the kernel is what is causing this issue

Comment: Now you can test backported kernels (currently there's `linux-image-6.5.0-0.deb12.1-amd64`) and see if hopefully it doesn't happen anymore. Then I guess doing a kind of git bissect would then be the next step, but if it can't be reproduced easily that's not really possible. Anyway a bug report might be in order because I don't see what can bring UL SE here, unless somebody *knowing* this exact problem sees the question and answers it. But we can still hope...